# Shell sort algorithm: shift or swap?

Tags: algorithm

I read that Shell algorithm is an improved version of insertion sort, but I also read online sometimes it is about shifting, and sometimes I read it is about swapping, which one is correct?

For example: `[5 3 2 10 0]`

If we take the gap to be 2, then we will compare first `5` and `2`, as a first step then, the result will be:
`[2 3 5 10 0]` by swapping and `[2 5 3 10 0]` by shifting, which one is Shell algorithm?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we take the gap to be 2, then we will compare first 5 and 2, as a first step then, the result will be: `[2 3 5 10 0]` by swapping and `[2 5 3 10 0]` by shifting, which one is Shell algorithm?

The main principle in Shell sort is that with the chosen gap we look at the data as a collection of interleaved, shorter arrays. Each of those shorter arrays has their first entry at an index less than `gap`. These shorter arrays are sorted **independently**. Once that is done, the gap is reduced.

In the example, there are two interleaved arrays, which we can picture like this:

```
interleaved array: 5    2    0
interleaved array:    3   10
```

The first algorithm would fit under Shell sort. But the second one does not sort the interleaved arrays *independently*, as such rotations (shifts) move values from one interleaved array to another:

```
interleaved array: 5    2     0
                    ⬊  ⬈
interleaved array:    3     10
```

...resulting in:

```
interleaved array: 2     3     0
interleaved array:    5     10
```

Unless other precautions are made, the second algorithm will not ensure a rotation improves the situation. For instance, if the input is `[3 1 2 4]` and gap is 2, then the comparison of 3 and 2 will lead to a rotation, and we get `[2 3 1 4]`. But now we still have two values in the first interleaved array that are not in order (2 is greater than 1).

#### Shifting?

Shifting does not occur like you depicted it (crossing multiple interleaved arrays), but within *one* interleaved array it is generally done, just like it is done in insertion sort. So to apply that to your example:

```
    interleaved array: 5    2    0
    interleaved array:    3   10
```

The value 2 is picked up and preceding values are shifted forward within the same interleaved array until the right slot is found for the picked up value. In this case only one value is shifted (5), which makes it a swap:

```
    interleaved array: 2    5    0
    interleaved array:    3   10
```

Now 0 is picked up, and two values are shifted (2 and 5):

```
    interleaved array: 0    2    5
    interleaved array:    3   10
```

Now the first interleaved array is sorted. The second interleaved array happens to be sorted already. Then the gap is reduced to 1:

```
    array: 0 3 2 10 5
```

Here 2 is picked up and one value (3) is shifted:

```
    array: 0 2 3 10 5
```

Finally 5 is picked up and one value (10) is shifted:

```
    array: 0 2 3 5 10
```

Comment: So basically we swap rather than shift, which makes sense, though when I read it is an improved version of insertion sort, I thought it uses shifting too, thanks

Comment: Yes, insertion sort uses shifting, and also Shell sort, but then it shifts within **one** interleaved array, not consecutive entries in the global array.

Comment: See a section I added to my answer.

Comment: I see, so the thing is that swapping in shell sort performs the same result of shifting elements in insertion sort, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean swapping x times consecutive elements is the same as making a rotation. This is more a question about insertion sort than shell sort.

Comment: I agree, but the issue only came out with the shell sort, but in insertion sort, shifting is required, not swapping, for example: `5 3 2 10 0` would follow these steps in insertion sort: `3 5 2 10 0` -> `2 3 5 10 0` -> `0 2 3 5 10`, if we swap it will be different for insertion sort, swapping will not work.

Comment: For your example insertion sort would first swap 5,3 (as you said), but then it would bring 2 into position with first a swap (5-2) and then a swap (3-2). The combined swap represents a rotation. When finally 0 is moved into place, it is swapped all the way to the start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251965/discussion-between-user21078706-and-trincot).